# SQLite ListView CursorIndexOutofBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I succeeded in setting up a ListView populated with pairs of Latitudes and Longitudes from an SQLite database. I wrote the code so that I could tap one of these pairs to call Google maps and navigate there from the user's current location. And when I held click, I got a dialogFragment asking me if I wanted to delete the LatLang pair; if the user confirmed, the pair would be deleted from the SQLite database, removed from the list, and the list repopulated.

After getting this working well, I tried to rewrite the code to include another column in the SQLite database to hold String labels for the LatLang pairs. But now, when I click a LatLang pair, instead of opening the Google maps intent, nothing happens. And when I hold click and then confirm the delete, the app crashes with a CursorIndexOutofBoundsException. I've tried debugging, reading further into this, and checking stackoverflow archives, but I'm still not sure what's going on.

If anyone sees anything obvious please let me know. I'm still very new to programming in general.

Here is my SQLite DatabaseHandler class:

```
package com.detimil.breadcrumbs1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "breadcrumbsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_BREADCRUMBS = "breadcrumbs";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_LABEL = "longitude";
private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_BREADCRUMBS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BREADCRUMBS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_LABEL + " TEXT," + KEY_LATITUDE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LONGITUDE + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BREADCRUMBS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_BREADCRUMBS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */


    // Adding new location/breadcrumb
public void addBreadcrumb(Breadcrumb breadcrumb) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_LABEL, breadcrumb.getBreadcrumbLabel()); // Label
        values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, breadcrumb.getBreadcrumbLatitude()); // Latitude
        values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, breadcrumb.getBreadcrumbLongitude()); // Longitude

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_BREADCRUMBS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    // Getting single breadcrumb
public Breadcrumb getBreadcrumb(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_BREADCRUMBS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_LABEL,
            KEY_LATITUDE, KEY_LONGITUDE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

//(I just edited this snippet as per advice from comment below. Unfortunately, the code still does not run correctly.)
if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
}
        Breadcrumb breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1),
        cursor.getInt(2), cursor.getInt(3));
    // return breadcrumb
    cursor.close();
    return breadcrumb;
}


    // Getting All breadcrumbs
    public List<Breadcrumb> getAllBreadcrumbs() {
 List<Breadcrumb> breadcrumbList = new ArrayList<Breadcrumb>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BREADCRUMBS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Breadcrumb breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
            breadcrumb.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            breadcrumb.setBreadcrumbLabel(cursor.getString(1));
            breadcrumb.setBreadcrumbLatitude(cursor.getInt(2));
            breadcrumb.setBreadcrumbLongitude(cursor.getInt(3));
            // Adding location to list
            breadcrumbList.add(breadcrumb);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return locations list
    cursor.close();
    return breadcrumbList;
}

// Getting All breadcrumb labels (leaving out the Lats and Langs)
public List<Breadcrumb> getAllBreadcrumbLabels() {
 List<Breadcrumb> breadcrumbLabelList = new ArrayList<Breadcrumb>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BREADCRUMBS;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Breadcrumb breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
        breadcrumb.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        breadcrumb.setBreadcrumbLabel(cursor.getString(2));
        // Adding label to list
        breadcrumbLabelList.add(breadcrumb);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return locations list
cursor.close();
return breadcrumbLabelList;
}

// Getting breadcrumbs/locations Count
    public int getBreadcrumbsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BREADCRUMBS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }


      //Updating single location
    public int updateBreadcrumbs(Breadcrumb breadcrumb) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_LABEL, breadcrumb.getBreadcrumbLabel());
        values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, breadcrumb.getBreadcrumbLatitude());
        values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, breadcrumb.getBreadcrumbLongitude());

         //updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_BREADCRUMBS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
              new String[] { String.valueOf(breadcrumb.getId()) });
    }

    // Deleting single location
      public void deleteBreadcrumb(Breadcrumb breadcrumb) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int id = breadcrumb.getId();
        System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + id);
        db.delete(TABLE_BREADCRUMBS, KEY_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
        db.close();
          }

}
```

And here is my activity with the ListView:

```
package com.detimil.breadcrumbs1;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class CollectedBreadcrumbsActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listview;
private DatabaseHandler db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_collected_breadcrumbs);

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    List<Breadcrumb> breadcrumbs = db.getAllBreadcrumbLabels();

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<Breadcrumb> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Breadcrumb>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, breadcrumbs);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

this.listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {

ArrayAdapter<Breadcrumb> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Breadcrumb>) listview.getAdapter();
if (listview.getAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
    Breadcrumb breadcrumb = db.getBreadcrumb(position);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps" + "&daddr=" + breadcrumb.getBreadcrumbLatitude()/1e6 + "," + breadcrumb.getBreadcrumbLongitude()/1e6));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    startActivity(intent);}}});

this.listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    Log.d("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);
    Log.d("HelloListView", "Number of items in adapter:" + listview.getAdapter().getCount());

    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(CollectedBreadcrumbsActivity.this);

    // set the message to display
    alertbox.setMessage("Delete Breadcrumb?");

    // set a positive/yes button and create a listener
    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {                
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayAdapter<Breadcrumb> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Breadcrumb>) listview.getAdapter();
            if (listview.getAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                Breadcrumb listedBreadcrumb = (Breadcrumb) listview.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                Breadcrumb breadcrumb = db.getBreadcrumb(position);
                db.deleteBreadcrumb(breadcrumb);
                adapter.remove(listedBreadcrumb);
                }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }
    });

    // set a negative/no button and create a listener
    alertbox.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        }
    });

    alertbox.show();

    return true;
    }
});

listview.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
}
}
```

The SQLite database is populated in the first place through clicking a button in the MainActivity. Below is the snippet of code that shows what happens when that button is pressed: it initiates another activity, and (in theory?) creates an SQLite row consisting of a String Label, a Latitude expressed as an int, and a Longitude expressed as an int.

```
public void dropBreadcrumb(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DroppedCrumb.class);
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    String label = "Breadcrumb"+db.getBreadcrumbsCount()+1; 
    BREADCRUMB_LATITUDE = (BREADCRUMB_LATITUDE * 1e6);
    int lat = (int)BREADCRUMB_LATITUDE;
    BREADCRUMB_LONGITUDE = (BREADCRUMB_LONGITUDE * 1e6);
    int lng = (int)BREADCRUMB_LONGITUDE;
    db.addBreadcrumb(new Breadcrumb(label, lat, lng));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is the actual error read I get when I hold a listView item and confirm that I want to delete it. The app crashes...

```
05-19 14:05:25.512: D/HelloListView(2086): You clicked Item: 0 at position:0
05-19 14:05:25.512: D/HelloListView(2086): Number of items in adapter:4
05-19 14:05:25.602: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(2086): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
05-19 14:05:26.653: W/dalvikvm(2086): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception ( (group=0x40e4c438)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at com.detimil.breadcrumbs1.DatabaseHandler.getBreadcrumb(DatabaseHandler.java:84)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at com.detimil.breadcrumbs1.CollectedBreadcrumbsActivity$2$1.onClick(CollectedBreadcrumbsActivity.java:72)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-19 14:05:26.663: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If you have any thoughts I'd be so grateful. Please let me know if any other piece of information/code would be useful to you.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT/Update:**

I just edited my getBreadcrumb method per user nikhil's initial suggestion below, but the primary problem is still there. Here are the error messages I get...

```
05-20 17:48:48.966: D/HelloListView(15738): You clicked Item: 2 at position:2
05-20 17:48:48.966: D/HelloListView(15738): Number of items in adapter:4
05-20 17:48:49.056: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(15738): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
05-20 17:48:50.297: W/dalvikvm(15738): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414db438)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at com.detimil.breadcrumbs1.DatabaseHandler.getBreadcrumb(DatabaseHandler.java:86)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at com.detimil.breadcrumbs1.CollectedBreadcrumbsActivity$2$1.onClick(CollectedBreadcrumbsActivity.java:72)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-20 17:48:50.297: E/AndroidRuntime(15738):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having 2 columns with same name longitude

```
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_LABEL = "longitude";
private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
```

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I didn't see that! (Must have been staring at this way too long.) I won't be able to retest out the code for several days but I'll post again to let you know if everything resolves.

Comment: It looks like the core problem remains, but obviously you found another big problem so thank you! (I can't upvote you yet because I don't have enough reputation.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your getBreadCrumb method.
When you long press the first row, the position variable is 0(zero), so when you pass this value to your getBreadCrumb method, the sql query fails(that means it returns no data) because id(primary key) always begins with 1. This problem is coming because of this statement:
public Breadcrumb getBreadcrumb(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_BREADCRUMBS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_LABEL,
        KEY_LATITUDE, KEY_LONGITUDE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Breadcrumb breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1),
```

}
The if condition is not satisfied thats why your cursor is not moved to point to first row so you are getting the error in logcat.
Modified code is:

```
public Breadcrumb getBreadcrumb(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_BREADCRUMBS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_LABEL,
        KEY_LATITUDE, KEY_LONGITUDE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
   { 
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       Breadcrumb breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0),
       cursor.getString(1),cursor.getInt(2),cursor.getInt(3));
//  return breadcrumb
   }
       cursor.close();
       return breadcrumb;
```

}

Notice the paranthesis around the if condition.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix the problem. I changed the code to `if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
   { 
       cursor.moveToFirst();
   }
       Breadcrumb breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0),
       cursor.getString(1),cursor.getInt(2),cursor.getInt(3));
//  return breadcrumb
       cursor.close();
       return breadcrumb;`

per your suggestion.

(Can't wrap the new Breadcrumb call in the parentheses or it won't recognize the breadcrumb variable as initialized later.)

I still get the same problem.

Comment: Ofcourse declare the BreadCrumb reference outside the if condition as:
BreadCrumb breadCrumb=null;
and then the if condition.

Comment: Yeah I tried this as well. It seems the problem is not just the getBreadcrumb method. (Although that method needed some fix as well so thank you.)

If you look at my original question, I added an update/edit showing error information I get when I try to longclick/delete another part of the listView, even after fixing the getBreadcrumb method.

Comment: Do you notice anything else about my code that's problematic? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: As i notice in your above code:
      if(cusor.getCount()>0)
This if condition is only satisfied if and only if the cursor contains some rows but this is not the case with your code. I think this error is coming from somewhere else.
Kindly paste your entire code for further help.